# ESlint rule for import naming?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to achieve something like. 
`import * as user from "../user"` <- this won't produce a warning 
`import * as myUsersPackage from "../user"` <- will produce a warning

I want the named import to be the same as the last bit of the path that the package is being imported from like `* as user` and `../user`
This is to have more consistent naming of `*` imported packages. Of course there will be naming conflicts so this shouldn't be a strictly enforced rule.

Is there anything like this that exists? And if I want to make this happen could I do it with the current tooling that eslint provides.

Comment: I suppose you can build a [custom rule](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules)